# Proof of the fact that $\{\text E[\xi\mid\mathcal F]:\mathcal F\}$ is uniformly integrable in Kallenberg

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, uniform-integrability

I don't understand the argument in the proof of Lemma 6.5 of Kallenberg's Foundations of Modern Probability (2nd edition):

[image: Kallenberg, Lemma 6-5]

Let $$\mathfrak A:=\{\mathcal F\subseteq\mathcal A:\mathcal F\text{ is a }\sigma\text{-algebra on }\Omega\}.$$ It is clear to me that it is sufficient to show that $$\sup_{\mathcal F\in\mathfrak A}\operatorname E\left[\left|\operatorname E\left[\xi\mid\mathcal F\right]\right|;A\right]\xrightarrow{\operatorname P[A]\:\to\:0}0\tag1.$$

Moreover, if $(\mathcal F_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq\mathfrak A$ and $(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq\mathcal A$ with $\operatorname P[A_n]\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$, then it clearly holds $(\operatorname P[A_n\mid\mathcal F_n])_{n\in\mathbb N}\to0$. In particular, there is an increasing $(n_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}\subseteq\mathbb N$ with $$\operatorname P\left[A_{n_k}\mid\mathcal F_{n_k}\right]\xrightarrow{k\to\infty}0\;\;\;\text{almost surely}\tag2$$ and hence $$\operatorname E\left[\left|\operatorname E\left[\xi\mid\mathcal F_{n_k}\right]\right|;A_{n_k}\right]\le\operatorname E\left[|X|\operatorname P\left[A_{n_k}\mid\mathcal F_{n_k}\right]\right]\xrightarrow{k\to\infty}0\tag3.$$

> But how do we obtain $(1)$ from that?

Comment: Did you miss a conditional expectation in (1)?  Otherwise, it follows from the fact that integrable random variables are uniformly integrable.

Comment: @PeterMorfe Yes, of course, there was a conditional expectation missing. Thanks for noting!

Comment: Limits of real numbers are determined by sequences so if (1) fails, there is a sequence $(A_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $(\mathcal{F}_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ along which it fails.